# Can't lunch opera browser with a selenium test with Java maven 4,0

Tags: java, maven, selenium, opera

```
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "operadriver.exe");
  ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
  options.setBinary("operadriver.exe");
  DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
  capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
  options.merge(capabilities);
  _driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

I put the operadriver.exe in the project main path and i'm having this error :

AILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeTest beforeTest
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Opera failed to start: was killed
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location operadriver.exe is no longer running, so OperaDriver is assuming that Opera has crashed.)
  (Driver info: OperaDriver=2.40 (a50783a565882ef2022bea655e8560f37ecf8afe),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 113 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08-02T20:13:22.693Z'
System info: host: 'Z500W23694', ip: '10.8.79.91', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_92'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code to launch google.com using operaBrowser.

```
    String operaBrowser = "C:\\......\\opera.exe"

    System.setProperty("webdriver.opera.driver", "C:\\user\drivers\\operadriver.exe");

    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.setBinary(operaBrowser);        

    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
    OperaDriver browser = new OperaDriver(capabilities);

    WebDriver driver =browser;
    driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
```

Comment: Thx its work , i want to lunch it by default without passing the param operaBrowswer so i can launch it in a Docker .

Comment: How to find the binary path on linux

Comment: use echo $PATH command